# Fix Broken Packages when no packages are broken?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

OK, I've tried everything and I'm still at a loss. When I try to install gimp (`sudo apt-get install gimp`) I get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've tried all the fixes: `apt-get update`, `apt-get autoremove`, `apt-get autoclean`, etc. and nothing fixes it. The problem is, I don't seem to have any broken packages. `dpkg -l` shows no packages with a problem.

Any suggestions? I'm running 64-bit 16.04

Comment: File a bug report against gimp

Comment: "apt-get update, apt-get autoremove, apt-get autoclean" are not fixes. Try fully updating your system first: `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` and post here the entire error messages if any.

Comment: No errors on those commands. Still get this when I try to install gimp (see next comment)

Comment: If tjay did not help back to filing a bug report

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: The bug is not in gimp - it's in dpkg. I've had the same problem trying to install other packages.

Comment: BTW: I tried installing  libgegl-0.3-0, and it has the same errors, but with another package that "is not going to be installed". Keep going... it gets to gcc-5-base. Appears to need 5.3.1 but 5.4.0 is installed.

Comment: It is not something you can easily fix so you need to file a bug report so the package maintainer can fix it

Comment: It's not a bug in GIMP or in dpkg or in anything; it's you who have messed up your system, probably by carelessly installing packages from unofficial sources.

Comment: @fkraiem - Perhpas, but you should ask for more information. libgegl is in Universe (as is gimp) https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libgegl&searchon=names . druid - you will get this error until it is fixed. Did you install packages from outside the ubuntu repositories, ie add a ppa or other repository or have you manually downloaded a .deb at some point and installed it with dpkg ?

Comment: @fkraiem - you may well be correct. But how do I fix it? How do I tell what package(s) is causing the problem?